# Does the version of ruby being used determine which openssl version is used, and by extension, TLS version(s) available?

Tags: ruby, openssl, tls1.2

TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are being deprecated and I want to make certain that it is not going to be used anywhere.  I am looking at a large number of repositories (with very little previous Ruby gem experience) and I don't see any direct references to TLS, but, I do see some references to openssl.

There is a helpful page concerning TLS deprecation: https://blog.rubygems.org/2018/02/24/tls-10-and-11-deprecation-notice.html

It contains a command: curl -sL https://git.io/vQhWq | ruby

While I can run this command locally against my various versions of installed (J)Ruby, I don't really know if this means anything relative to a large production environment.

**Is the version of openssl always determined by the version of ruby in use**, ***or am I missing something?*** Even if my local install of ruby 2.5.5 indicates openssl 1.1.1g and 1.1.1i (compiled and loaded versions, respectively) and these versions of OpenSSL do not support TLS versions below 1.2, could the prod environment could still be using ruby 2.5.5 with TLS below 1.2?

Answer (score 0):

First, it is important to understand the parts involved:

Ruby (the language) includes the [openssl extension](https://github.com/ruby/openssl). The extension is compiled and linked against an openssl library. You can, I believe, also install the openssl extension as a gem in which case the gem's extension will be compiled and linked against *an* openssl library, though this configuration is very rare (people would usually recompile all of Ruby to rebuild their openssl extension).

In theory, whenever the openssl extension is compiled it can reference a distinct copy of openssl library. When the extension is loaded at runtime it can reference a distinct copy of the library also, and not necessarily the same one that the extension was compiled against.

MOST Ruby installations utilize the systemwide openssl library, and there is only one library in play regardless of how many Ruby versions are built and installed. But some installations have multiple openssl libraries involved, for example when the system library is too old or too new for the particular application's desires.

Now, the *version* (as in version number) of Ruby only matters to the extent that each version ships a particular version of the openssl extension. This mostly makes a difference at compile time, in that old Rubies don't build with recent openssls. Assuming a typical Ruby installation which includes the openssl extension, once the extension is built it'll generally work with the same version of openssl library that was used during compilation or newer.

What I suggest you do is:

1. Find all OpenSSL installations on the system you are analyzing, find out how they are configured, check for appropriate/inappropriate configuration.
2. Find all OpenSSL extension copies (`openssl.so`) the system you are analyzing and figure out what openssl libraries they are linked against.

Note that the version number of Ruby, as well as how many Ruby installations you have, is only irrelevant insofar as this gets you to the respective installed openssl extensions.

Which OpenSSL library is used can be overridden at runtime (LD_LIBRARY_PATH, etc.) therefore only looking at defaults is insufficient if you want to be thorough.

JRuby has [its own openssl extension](https://github.com/jruby/jruby-openssl) which I assume uses Java's SSL functionality. To verify this, create a VM/docker container, uninstall everything openssl-related from there,  install JRuby and check TLS functionality. If JRuby does not use OpenSSL library you would need to work out what TLS functionality your installed Java runtime(s) provide.